# Alternative ways to perform 'cv::flip(img, img, 1)'

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I am receiving an image in the form of raw data from a sensor insied ROS. Following fields are known:

- Width: 1920
- Height: 1080
- Encoding: BGRA8
- Bytes Per Pixel: 4
- Image Data: 1-D byte array having 8294400 elements //1920 * 1080 * 4 = 8294400

I need to visualize this image in ROS hence I am composing ROS supported image as follows:

```
std::basic_string<char> color_pixels = color_frame.data();

//Step 1: Create OpenCV image
cv::Mat image(cv::Size(color_frame.width(), color_frame.height()), CV_8UC4, const_cast<char*>(color_pixels.data()), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);

//Step 2: Convert OpenCV image to CvBridge image
cv_bridge::CvImage cv_image;
cv_image.header.frame_id = frame_id;
cv_image.encoding = "bgra8";
cv_image.image = image;

//Step 3: Convert CvBridge image to ROS image
sensor_msgs::Image ros_image;
cv_image.toImageMsg(ros_image);
```

This looks fine. However, during visualization, I noticed that image is flipped. Hence in order to restore it back, I have to use `cv::flip` before step 2 in following way:

```
cv::flip(image, image, 1);
```

Since I have all the raw values and the above process seems long, I decided to compose `sensor_msgs::Image` directly. However, I am not able to perform `cv::flip` operation.

Below are my queries:

1. Why is `flip` required? Is the raw data captured incorrectly?
2. Is it possible to perform the operation similar to `cv::flip` directly in a byte array?

**My approach**
I tried to reverse the byte array but it didn't work. Please see below the code snippet:

```
std::basic_string<char> color_pixels = color_data.data();
std::vector<unsigned char> color_values(color_pixels.begin(), color_pixels.end());
std::reverse(color_values.begin(), color_values.end());

sensor_msgs::Image ros_image;
//width, height, encoding etc. are set but not shown here
ros_image.data = color_values;
```

Comment: 1. You don't show us how you capture the data, so this is impossible to answer at this point. 2. You make `cv::Mat` header for the raw data array, and call `cv::flip` on that `Mat`. (Just what you were doing in the first place)

Comment: @DanMašek: 1. The data was captured from Kinect sensor using [CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.copyconvertedframedatatoarray.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp) 2. I couldn't understand this point. what do you want to say? Well, in my question above, I meant that `cv::flip` was needed in order to correct the view. Hence first `cv::Mat image` was created and then `cv::flip(image, image, 1)` was applied on it.

Comment: What i'm saying is that given a raw array that is flipped around the vertical axis, the best way to turn it back to normal is using the `cv::flip` as you did in the first place.

Comment: @DanMašek: You are right. Let me explain it again. Finally after doing `cv::flip` and other operations, I am getting [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo) image i.e., [sensor_msgs::Image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html). Hence, I thought of creating `sensor_msgs::Image` directly from raw data. I am able to create it but the image needs to be flipped. Earlier, this flip was done using `cv::flip(image, image, 1)`. I want to know how to do `cv::flip(image, image, 1)` on `sensor_msgs::Image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you can set up your camera to flip the image.  That is the proper place to specify this.  (Sometimes, our cameras are mounted upside down)

since your byte array is {b0, g0, r0, a0, b1, g1, r1, a1, ...}, simply reversing it will result in a {aN, rN, gN, bN, ...}, and your format becomes argb.  **`cv::flip` already accounts for this**.  Just saying " the above process seems long" is not enough reason to do this by yourself: it will complicate your code, and will result in a poor replication of what the opencv guys already provided you with.

If you *really* want to write that yourself, maybe `b = reinterpret_cast<BRGRA*>(&color_data.data().front())`, and do the `reverse` on the reinterpreted 'structs'.

```
struct BRGRA { char b, g, r, a };
std::reverse(
  reinterpret_cast<BRGRA*>( &data.front() ),
  reinterpret_cast<BRGRA*>( &data.back() ) + 1,
  reinterpret_cast<BRGRA*>( &data.front() ));
```

-- EDIT

The fact that this answer was accepted without additional comments to the suggested code proves the point that it's hard to provide better than a 'poor replication': above snippet will reverse [image: matrix abcd] into [image], turning it upside-down.  (viewed 'only' 40 times, but still...).  So it can only work for single-line images.

Comment: I am trying to understand this answer. Meanwhile let me clarify that while visualization, the objects on left side was shown at right side and vice a versa. After using `cv::flip(img, img, 1)` the left side objects are now shown at left and similarly right side objects are shown in right side.